# Modifying a list in python by passing it to a function

Tags: python, list, function

I have the following python code:

```
def make_great(l):
    l = ['The great ' + magician for magician in l]

magicians = ['Tom']
make_great(magicians)
print(magicians)
```

The print statement prints the original list, not the one modified by the `make_great()` function. I was trying to figure out a way of modifying each element of a python list without explicitly accessing it's index and then reassigning that index a new value. Wouldn't the `magicians` list now point to the new list formed by the comprehension based on Python's memory model ? I am guessing that I am not getting the desired results because this is a scoping issue ? But when I pass in `magicians` , it replaces `l` in the function argument so the python interpreter actually sees `magicians = ['The ...` ?

Comment: The problem is that you're modifying the local variable `l` to refer to a new object.  Instead, you should modify the object referred to by `l`.

Comment: I'm confused, when I use the index notation, `l[i]` to modify the list, why is that not considered a local variable, but when I use the `=` operator to reassign `magicians` to a new list, it's now considered local ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm considering renaming `l` variable name to `lst` or other better readable name as it prevents confusion with number `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign it to `l`, you are redefining `l`, not modifying it.  Use `l[:]` instead:

```
def make_great(l):
    l[:] = ['The great ' + magician for magician in l]
```

You could also return the list and redefine `magicians`:

```
def make_great(l):
    return ['The great ' + magician for magician in l]

magicians = ['Tom']
magicians = make_great(magicians)
print(magicians)
```

In that case, you could assign `magicians` to `make_great(['Tom'])`:

```
magicians = make_great(['Tom'])
print(magicians)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning anything. You can either have your print statement in the function or return the modified list and then print it

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_great(l):
    return ['The great ' + magician for magician in l]

magicians = ['Tom']
magicians = make_great(magicians)
print(magicians)
```

The make_great function duplicates your array, so you need to return and assign the result to magicians.

You can check [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) for passing reference or values in functions